# how to represent object as variable for graph of seaborn in python?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have data-frame which has column name price. So i want to draw a distribution plot for that column. and i want to assign the graph name as column_name so that i can the graph when i need in multiple places even though i have number of distribution, I can call required graph separately, here i have column are dynamic.

```
x = 'price'
y = sns.distplot(df[x])
exec("%s = %s" % (x,y))
print(price)
```

I have try this code but throwing an error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/mahesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3287, in run_code
last_expr = (yield from self._async_exec(code_obj, self.user_ns))

File "<ipython-input-36-f28fdca73b33>", line 8, in async-def-wrapper

File "<string>", line 1
price = AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I don't think the line `exec("%s = %s" % (x,y))` makes much sense. What would you expect from it? maybe `exec("%s = y" % x)` comes closer to what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

One way is using a function

```
x = df.price

def displot(j):
    sns.distplot(j)

displot(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for information. But I don't want use function to call graph, because i'm going to put this code in production. if i put in production graphs all columns plot in only on graph like

Comment: Thanks for information. But if call function in production it gets multiple plots of dataframe in single graph. so i want to call by column_name